# Separate Bootstrap badge by Postgres array / json in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

This is my screen capture from live server:

[image]

According from my attached picture. I have been trying to split the information from array and json by bootstrap. I want to separate each value from array or json by separated badge.

by this script:

```
                                    {% for info in qa_info %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>{{info.id}}</th>
                                            <td>{{info.fullname}}</td>
                                            <td><span id="skilltag" class="badge badge-primary light">{{info.skills_a}}
                                            </span></td>
                                            <td>{{info.pos}}</td>
                                            <td class="color-primary">{{info.nickname}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
```

> The data came from Postgresql array and json column

Answer (score 0):

What are contents in qa_info, or the structure. If it is what you have in the above image, then it is an array of strings but you are treating it as a json object containing key value pairs.
It would be great if you put the contents of qa_info.

Comment: I have coding with Django project then I need to import array by {{info.skills_a}} but data type in this column is text[] in Postgres